# Communication between Different programs in Different Computers (C# or Python)

Tags: networking

I'm building a program that I want to be able to exchange information with other programs running in another computer. I started using C# and a library called SimpleTCP. The main issue is that is too simple and only send and receive messages.
I'm looking for something that I can predetermine functions that one or the other can call from each other.
I looked on google and stack overflow but I was unable to find an appropriated subject to study, what should I be looking for to learn this? Thank you

Comment: "only send and receive messages"—what more do you need? Send a message from A to B. When B receives it, run a function.

Comment: Anyway, this is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. You might want to research [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Comment: Use SimpleTCP to send some JSON back and forth if you want to keep things relatively low key but work with an established standard (and all the relevant implemented parsers etc) for data interchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete protocol for what you want is [gRPC](https://grpc.io/). There is a learning curve but worth it in my opinion. https://github.com/grpc/grpc

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but it's little bit different 
Such programs like this *written in tow different languages*
You can make a  center database between the both programs 
In this situation it's very easy to communicate and receive ,send data 
You can mysql ,oracl, mariadb or any Database you prefer